# dojo - lang.hitch for widget function

Tags: javascript, scope, dojo, widget, dom-events

I have a custom widget and I am curious if I can use `lang.hitch` in a particular way.  Here is the scenario:

Say I have a custom widget that contains a `Button`.  That `Button` needs a function attached to its `onClick` event.  So, in my template I have:

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick : _onButtonClick" />
```

Then, in my widget `.js` file I have:

```
_onButtonClick : function(evt) {
    //do something here that needs the scope of my widget (this)
}
```

I know I could remove the `data-dojo-attach-event` from my template and use `dojo.connect` with `lang.hitch` in `postCreate`, but I'm wondering if I could just simply convert the `_onButtonClick` function to this:

```
_onButtonClick : lang.hitch(this, function(evt) {
    //do something here that needs the scope of my widget (this)
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Using `hitch` in your example uses more code, and the `this` reference won't be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-dojo-attach-event` automatically makes the scope of `this` be the parent widget.

I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think the context of `this` in the snippet
    declare([/*deps*/,{

```
    _onButtonClick : lang.hitch(this, function(evt) {
      //do something here that needs the scope of my widget (this)
    })

});
```

is what you want to.  I believe when that function is bound it will be the scope that the declare function is executed in, rather than the instance of the widget.

Comment: I've found that if I have a `Button` in my widget template with `data-dojo-attach-event`, when I debug the event function `this` represents the `Button` and not my widget.

Comment: @Brian: Did you find any solution to this? I am having a similar scenario where I would like to have the access to the widget object on click of child widget (say Button)